# I can't find the definition of the 'on' method in flux example, todomvc. what does it do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

on line 107 of TodoStore.js:

```
   /**
   * @param {function} callback
   */
  addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },
```

link:  https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/stores/TodoStore.js

Comment: I am learning flux and reactjs, i think the best way to learn programming is to read code. but this 'on' method really confused me. I can't find the definition anywhere.

Comment: I don't know about react or flux, but I'll bet it's pretty similar to [jQuery's on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is using the [Node Events module](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html), which defines EventEmitter. The two lines that show you what is going on are:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
```

And…

```
var TodoStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought flux uses fbemitter. I didn't notice that it uses node events module.